Optimistic lock problem ( return entity no problem, return void optimistic lock)
The first method is working fine, but the others are returning errors. Why am I getting these errors? Both methods have the same purpose; however, one of them returns an entity, while the others do not.
**Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.x.y.z.entity.Customer#6542]
Object of class [com.x.y.z.entity.Customer#6542] optimistic locking failed nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction.
**
@Override
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = CacheConstants.CUSTOMER_CACHE, key = "#customer.token + #customer.customerToken", cacheManager = "redisCacheManager")
public Customer updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
    return repository.save(customer); // NO ERROR
}

@Override
public void updateCustomerStatus(Customer customer, TokenStatus status) {
    customer.setStatus(status);
    repository.save(customer); // ERROR (OPT. LOCK)
}

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updateCustomerStatus(Customer customer, TokenStatus status) {
    customer.setStatus(status);
    repository.save(customer); // ERROR (OPT. LOCK)
}

@Override
public void updateCustomerStatus(Customer customer, TokenStatus status) {
    customer.setStatus(status);
    repository.saveAndFlush(customer); // ERROR (OPT. LOCK)
}

Used transactional,
used different save method.
